# add worklog to JIRA (with user and activity metadata) using the API

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using jira-python and request API to log work to JIRA tickets with the user and activity info but can't figure out a way to do it . I have the following code :

```
jira.add_worklog("issue number", timeSpent="2h", user="username")
```

but it seems to ignore the user keyword. I am also looking up JIRA API with request library but can't seem to find an API to log work with activity and user info.

Answer (score 4):

It is not needed to add inside the arguments the user. you can use the following code:

```
jira.add_worklog("issue number", timeSpent="2h")
```

Yo can add other arguments like:

- adjustEstimate – (optional) allows the user to provide specific instructions to update the remaining time estimate of the issue. The value can either be new, leave, manual or auto (default).
- newEstimate – the new value for the remaining estimate field. e.g. “2d”
- reduceBy – the amount to reduce the remaining estimate by e.g. “2d”
- started – Moment when the work is logged, if not specified will default to now
- comment – optional worklog comment

You can find more info about it in [jira python api](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira.JIRA.add_worklog)

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct support for this action, see this discussed in

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/29951977

and

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-30197

It's possible to impersonate another user, either by writing an add-on with the  `ACT_AS_USER` scope or by registering your application with Oauth2 authentication in your Jira configuration, for example as discussed here:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/247528/how-do-you-impersonate-a-user-with-jira-oauth

You'd probably be better off discussing implantation suggestions on answers.atlassian.com.